# WebRtc на сайте

Tags: веб-программирование, web-camera

Здравствуйте! Как можно реализовать технологию WebRtc на сайте, чтобы 2 пользователя могли общаться между собой. Просто манов в сети очень мало.

Comment: Этот вопрос очень обширный, то же самое, если бы вы спросили: "Как написать сайт на PHP?"

Comment: Неплохой вот этот курс – http://learnfromlisa.com/learn-webrtc/

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос, на самом деле, правильный. А манов не мало, их много и противоречивых.
В частности, google предлагает google app engine, а остальные - около 70%, в основном, websockets для signaling (установления соединения). Технологии не очень совместимы, увы. А в стандарте signaling вообще не прописан (так специально сделано, чтобы разработчики пользовались чем удобнее).
Рекомендую посмотреть код тут:

https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/

Answer (score 0):

для [Chrome](http://www.webrtc.org/chrome) и для [firefox](http://www.webrtc.org/firefox)